# How to read xls file in laravel - laravel-excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I'm using `laravel-excel` library to read excel files.

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import

```
   //http://localhost:8000/assets/panel/excel/test123.xls
    $address = URL::to('/assets/panel/excel/').'/test123.xls';
   // dd($address);
    Excel::load($address, function($reader) {

        $results = $reader->get();
        dd($results);

    });
```

this file `http://localhost:8000/assets/panel/excel/test123.xls` exist but I got this error:

```
Could not open C:\xampp\htdocs\tahrircenter\http://localhost:8000/assets/panel/excel/test123.xls for reading! File does not exist.
```

I know the meaning of the error, but how can I use my address instead of directory address in this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Just tested and the following should work:

```
// /routes/web.php
Route::get('excel-test', function () {
    // http://localhost/assets/panel/excel/test123.xls
    // /public/assets/panel/excel/test123.xls
    $address = './assets/panel/excel/test123.xls';
    Excel::load($address, function($reader) {
        $results = $reader->get();
        dd($results);
    });
});
```

Laravel Excel is based on PHPExcel code by [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

One of the examples from PHPExcel documentation has the following code:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader01.php#L29

**Solution 2**

You can use `public_path()` Laravel helper function as well:

```
Route::get('excel-test', function () {
    $address = public_path('assets/panel/excel/test123.xls');
    Excel::load($address, function($reader) {
        $results = $reader->get();
        dd($results);
    });
});
```

**Discussion**

Portion of a file that generates an error:

```
// /vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php
public function canRead($pFilename)
{
    // Check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {
        throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

As You can see PHPExcel uses `file_exists()` PHP function to check, if the file exists. `file_exists()` can check local path only and not the remote path / URL.